# 2013 Bravia display IP control

Tags: api, ip, controls, television

I'm trying to control a 2013 Bravia display through Ethernet and I would need the API for it.
I've done some work and it's working but I need the commands to control the tuner section or something that emulates the infrared remote controller.
Is it possible to acquire it somewhere??